# Баг в обрисовке букв - ограничение на количество точек кривой?

Tags: php, imagick

Есть некоторый текст, который выводится на пустую картинку с помощью `annotateImage`. Задается толщина обводки таким образом:

```
$draw->setStrokeColor('#000');
$draw->setStrokeWidth(8);
```

Первая буква (или несколько) обводится нормально, следующая или даже первая выводится со сломаной кривой (глюком). Последующие без обводки:

[image: Это несколько одинаковых букв J]

*Это несколько одинаковых букв J*

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

*Вариант с более простым шрифтом*

Из этого я делаю вывод, что есть какое-то ограничение на количество точек при обводке. Можно ли задать это число? как это исправить?

Версия - 3.4.3 - модуль, imagick - 6.8.9-9

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Однако, на этой-же самой версии на другом пк проблемы не наблюдается

Comment: Мне кажется, дело не в количестве точек, а в том, что алгоритм путается в пересекающихся линиях шрифта. Попробуйте использовать другой шрифт.

Comment: @ЕгорБанин нет, тестировано много раз. Дело в количестве. Специально для вас добавил еще тест

Comment: А какая версия модуля? Тестировали в вакууме (только аннотация и обводка)? У меня не воспроизводится пока.

Comment: @ЕгорБанин на локалке такого нет, на хосте проблема имеется. Версия модуля не знаю какая, php 7.1

Comment: На сервере можно глянуть `phpinfo(INFO_MODULES);`. Вероятно баг imagick'а.

Comment: @ЕгорБанин - 3.4.3 - модуль, imagick - 6.8.9-9